# Tamanho de uma lista de lista usando list.capacity

Tags: c#, .net, lista

Se crio uma lista de listas:

```
List<List<int>> myList = new List<List<int>>();
```

Adiciono elementos em `myList` com 1 elemento:

```
myList.Add(1);
```

Quando faço `debug.writeLine(myList.capacity)` **me retorna o valor 4**, sendo que minha lista só possui 1 elemento.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sim, é isto mesmo, por otimização uma lista, na implementação atual, começa com 4 elementos e toda vez que a capacidade estourar ela dobra de tamanho. Quando uma lista não tem mais capacidade precisa criar um novo *array* (existe um interno na lista) e copiar todos os dados do *array* existente para o novo, que é algo ineficiente e gera pressão para o *garbage collector*, então essa estrutura tenta minimizar isso já começando com um valor mínimo e aumenta cada vez mais conforme vai crescendo porque se você está crescendo muito provavelmente vai crescer mais ainda, e quanto maior fica mais complicado fica a cópia, então deve evitar mais ainda.

Isso ocorre para evitar o chamado [Shlemiel the painter's algorithm](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/).

[image: Shlemiel the painter's algorithm]

Sim, ocupará o espaço de 4 elementos no *array*, mesmo que só use um, ou nenhum, mas não faz diferença prática.

Note que capacidade é diferente de quanto elementos efetivamente tem. Se você quer saber quantidade de elementos deve pegar a propriedade `Count`, assim:

```
myList.Count
```

Se deseja mesmo criar uma lista com um elemento, o que não recomendo, pode fazer:

```
new List<List<int>>(1)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Collection/Capacity.cs).

Pode ser 0 se quiser. O ideal é usar este parâmetro para indicar mais ou menos a quantidade que espera que a lista vá ter para evitar alocações desnecessárias, então deve fazer o oposto, se espera que a lista vá ter centenas de elementos, criar com tamanho 1000 é de grande valia e otimizará absurdamente. Mesmo que desperdice espaço por não usar tudo costuma ser uma solução melhor.

Comment: Obrigado pela Explicação.
Não irei armazenar somente um elemento na lista, foi somente para exemplificar meu problema :)